# Condense Time Periods with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a large data set which for the purpose of this question has 3 fields:

- Group Identifier
- From Date
- To Date

On any given row the `From Date` will always be less than the `To Date` but within each group the time periods (which are in no particular order) represented by the date pairs could overlap, be contained one within another, or even be identical.

What I'd like to end up with is a query that condenses the results for each group down to just the continuous periods. For example a group that looks like this:

```
| Group ID | From Date  | To Date    |
--------------------------------------
| A        | 01/01/2012 | 12/31/2012 |
| A        | 12/01/2013 | 11/30/2014 |
| A        | 01/01/2015 | 12/31/2015 |
| A        | 01/01/2015 | 12/31/2015 |
| A        | 02/01/2015 | 03/31/2015 |
| A        | 01/01/2013 | 12/31/2013 |
```

Would result in this:

```
| Group ID | From Date  | To Date    |
--------------------------------------
| A        | 01/01/2012 | 11/30/2014 |
| A        | 01/01/2015 | 12/31/2015 |
```

I've read a number of articles on date packing but I can't quite figure out how to apply that to my data set.

How can construct a query that would give me those results?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Why re-inventing the wheel? Itzik Ben-Gan wrote multiple articles on packing intervals, e.g. http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution from book "Microsoft® SQL Server ® 2012 High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions"

```
;with C1 as(
select GroupID, FromDate as ts, +1 as type, 1 as sub
  from dbo.table_name
union all
select GroupID, dateadd(day, +1, ToDate) as ts, -1 as type, 0 as sub
  from dbo.table_name),
C2 as(
select C1.*
     , sum(type) over(partition by GroupID order by ts, type desc
                      rows between unbounded preceding and current row) - sub as cnt
  from C1),
C3 as(
select GroupID, ts, floor((row_number() over(partition by GroupID order by ts) - 1) / 2 + 1) as grpnum
  from C2
  where cnt = 0)

select GroupID, min(ts) as FromDate, dateadd(day, -1, max(ts)) as ToDate
  from C3
  group by GroupID, grpnum;
```

Create table:

```
if object_id('table_name') is not null
  drop table table_name
create table table_name(GroupID varchar(100), FromDate datetime,ToDate datetime)
insert into table_name
select 'A', '01/01/2012', '12/31/2012' union all
select 'A', '12/01/2013', '11/30/2014' union all
select 'A', '01/01/2015', '12/31/2015' union all
select 'A', '01/01/2015', '12/31/2015' union all
select 'A', '02/01/2015', '03/31/2015' union all
select 'A', '01/01/2013', '12/31/2013'
```

Comment: I'm going to test it a bit more but so far this answer seems to give the best results and have the best performance.

Comment: in the book mentioned you can find a very detailed explanation (Chapter 5, Packing Intervals)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `Calendar` table. This table simply has a list of dates for several decades.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [dt] [date] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dt] ASC
))
```

There are many ways to [populate such table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1).

For example, 100K rows (~270 years) from 1900-01-01:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (dt)
SELECT TOP (100000) 
    DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1, '19000101') AS dt
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Once you have a `Calendar` table, here is how to use it.

Each original row is joined with the `Calendar` table to return as many rows as there are dates between From and To.

Then possible duplicates are removed.

Then classic gaps-and-islands by numbering the rows in two sequences.

Then grouping found islands together to get the new From and To.

**Sample data**

I added a second group.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (GroupID int, FromDate date, ToDate date);
INSERT INTO @T (GroupID, FromDate, ToDate) VALUES
(1, '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'),
(1, '2013-12-01', '2014-11-30'),
(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'),
(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'),
(1, '2015-02-01', '2015-03-31'),
(1, '2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'),
(2, '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'),
(2, '2013-01-01', '2013-12-31');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_AllDates
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T.GroupID
        ,CA.dt
    FROM
        @T AS T
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT dbo.Calendar.dt
            FROM dbo.Calendar
            WHERE
                dbo.Calendar.dt >= T.FromDate
                AND dbo.Calendar.dt <= T.ToDate
        ) AS CA
)
,CTE_Sequences
AS
(
    SELECT
        GroupID
        ,dt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY dt) AS Seq1
        ,DATEDIFF(day, '2001-01-01', dt) AS Seq2
        ,DATEDIFF(day, '2001-01-01', dt) - 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY dt) AS IslandNumber
    FROM CTE_AllDates
)
SELECT
    GroupID
    ,MIN(dt) AS NewFromDate
    ,MAX(dt) AS NewToDate
FROM CTE_Sequences
GROUP BY GroupID, IslandNumber
ORDER BY GroupID, NewFromDate;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+-------------+------------+
| GroupID | NewFromDate | NewToDate  |
+---------+-------------+------------+
|       1 | 2012-01-01  | 2014-11-30 |
|       1 | 2015-01-01  | 2015-12-31 |
|       2 | 2012-01-01  | 2013-12-31 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
; with 
cte as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by [Group ID] order by [From Date])
    from    tbl
),
rcte as
(
    select  rn, [Group ID], [From Date], [To Date], GrpNo = 1, GrpFrom = [From Date], GrpTo = [To Date]
    from    cte
    where   rn  = 1

    union all

    select  c.rn, c.[Group ID], c.[From Date], c.[To Date], 
        GrpNo = case    when    c.[From Date] between r.GrpFrom and dateadd(day, 1, r.GrpTo)
                or  c.[To Date]   between r.GrpFrom and r.GrpTo
                then    r.GrpNo
                else    r.GrpNo + 1
                end,
        GrpFrom= case   when    c.[From Date] between r.GrpFrom and dateadd(day, 1, r.GrpTo)
                or  c.[To Date]   between r.GrpFrom and r.GrpTo
                then    case when c.[From Date] > r.GrpFrom then c.[From Date] else r.GrpFrom end
                else    c.[From Date] 
                end,
        GrpTo  = case   when    c.[From Date] between r.GrpFrom and dateadd(day, 1, r.GrpTo)
                or  c.[To Date]   between r.GrpFrom and dateadd(day, 1, r.GrpTo)
                then    case when c.[To Date] > r.GrpTo then c.[To Date] else r.GrpTo end
                else    c.[To Date]  
                end

    from    rcte r
        inner join cte c    on  r.[Group ID]    = c.[Group ID]
                    and r.rn        = c.rn - 1
)
select  [Group ID], min(GrpFrom), max(GrpTo)
from    rcte
group by [Group ID], GrpNo
```

Comment: Right now it doesn't return correct result even for the given sample data. And it will not work correctly when there are more than one `Group ID`.

Comment: Try to add another Group ID to the table. For example, with these two extra rows result is not correct: `(2, '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31')` and `(2, '2013-01-01', '2013-12-31')`.

Comment: amended the query. Missed the Partition By

Comment: These results seem ok but it also seems to choke on all but very small datasets.

Answer (score 1):

### A Geometric Approach

Here and [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561130/merge-overlapping-date-intervals) I've noticed that date packing questions
don't provide a geometric approach to this problem.  After all,
any range, date-ranges included, can be interpreted as a line.
So why not convert them to a sql geometry type and utilize 
`geometry::UnionAggregate` to merge the ranges.  So I gave a stab 
at it with your post.

### Code Description

In 'numbers':

- I build a table representing a sequence
- Swap it out with your favorite way to make a numbers table.
- For a union operation, you won't ever need more rows than in 
  your original table, so I just use it as the base to build it.

In 'mergeLines':

- I convert the dates to floats and use those floats
  to create geometrical points.
- In this problem, we're working in 
  'integer space,' meaning there are no time considerations, and so
  an begin date in one range that is one day apart from an end date
  in another should be merged with that other.  In order to make 
  that merge happen, we need to convert to 'real space.', so we 
  add 1 to the tail of all ranges (we undo this later).
- I then connect these points via STUnion and STEnvelope.
- Finally, I merge all these lines via UnionAggregate.  The resulting
  'lines' geometry object might contain multiple lines, but if they
  overlap, they turn into one line.

In the outer query:

- I use the numbers CTE to extract the individual lines inside 'lines'.
- I envelope the lines which here ensures that the lines are stored
  only as its two endpoints.
- I read the endpoint x values and convert them back to their time 
  representations, ensuring to put them back into 'integer space'.

### The Code

```
with

    numbers as (

        select  row_number() over (order by (select null)) i 
        from    @spans -- Where I put your data

    ),

    mergeLines as (

        select      groupId,
                    lines = geometry::UnionAggregate(line)
        from        @spans
        cross apply (select 
                        startP = geometry::Point(convert(float,fromDate), 0, 0),
                        stopP = geometry::Point(convert(float,toDate) + 1, 0, 0)
                    ) pointify
        cross apply (select line = startP.STUnion(stopP).STEnvelope()) lineify
        group by    groupId 

    )

    select      groupId, fromDate, toDate 
    from        mergeLines ml
    join        numbers n on n.i between 1 and ml.lines.STNumGeometries()
    cross apply (select line = ml.lines.STGeometryN(i).STEnvelope()) l
    cross apply (select 
                    fromDate = convert(datetime, l.line.STPointN(1).STX),
                    toDate = convert(datetime, l.line.STPointN(3).STX) - 1
                ) unprepare
    order by    groupId, fromDate;
```