# Find max of total days using Partition By

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Need SQL Query to get a max of the sum of Days where enddate is equal to startdate
.Below is a table

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 01-01-2022 | 01-03-2022 | 2 |
| 121 | 01-03-2022 | 01-04-2022 | 1 |
| 121 | 01-04-2022 | 01-06-2022 | 2 |
| 121 | 01-07-2022 | 01-08-2022 | 1 |
| 121 | 01-08-2022 | 01-09-2022 | 1 |

In the above table, the 01-01-2022 to 01-06-2022 sum is 5 which is greater than the sum of 2 from 01-07-2022 to 01-09-2022.
Output required

| ID | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 121 | 5 |

Comment: *Need SQL Query* -- This website is not a free code writing service.  What have you tried so far and what are the issues you are facing with your scripts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge overlapping date intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561130/merge-overlapping-date-intervals). Or [Overlapping effective dates aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415749/overlapping-effective-dates-aggregation)

Comment: I have written recursive CTE for same but its taking long time and not best practice, therefore  looking for partition by

Comment: *"I have written recursive CTE for same but its taking long time and not best practice"* -- Please include this script within your question and provide details on why you think it is not best practice

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have written as per my understanding. correct me if I did worse

```
with table as (
  select 121 id, "12-28-2021" startdate, "12-30-2021" enddate, 2 days
  union all
  select 121 id, "12-30-2021" startdate, "12-31-2021" enddate, 1 days
  union all 
  select 121 id, "01-01-2022" startdate, "01-03-2022" enddate, 2 days
  union all
  select 121 id, "01-03-2022" startdate, "01-04-2022" enddate, 1 days
  union all 
  select 121 id, "01-04-2022" startdate, "01-06-2022" enddate, 2 days
  union all 
  select 121 id, "01-07-2022" startdate, "01-08-2022" enddate, 1 days
  union all 
  select 121 id, "01-08-2022" startdate, "01-09-2022" enddate, 1 days
)
select
  table3.id,
  max(days) days
from
  (
    select 
      table2.id,
      sum(days) days
    from
      (
        select 
          table1.*,
          case 
            when sum(x) over(rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) is null then 0
            else sum(x) over(rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
          end as y
        from
          (
            select 
            table.*,
            case 
              when enddate = lead(startdate) over(order by startdate) then 0
              else 1 
            end as x
          from table
          ) table1
      ) table2
    group by id,y
  ) table3
group by id
```